# SSDP Replies with a IPv6 Header

Tags: ipv6, upnp, ssdp

I am using a Custom made SSDP Search Request Program which multicasts a MSEARCH request to address "239.255.255.250" . The problem is the Request reaches every other host machine in the Network but some of the systems with UPnP services enabled replies with a IPv6 Destination Header which is not understood by the host program .I tried disabling the IPv6 from these devices but it wont work either.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to deal with IPv6, especially on the LAN. It is in use in lots of places (Apple AirPlay, Windows Home Group etc) so you cannot expect it to be turned off anymore these days.